# Is there a reason that my self.x and self.y v variables are over 20 when using the generation class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

```
import random, pygame, numpy

#window setup aswell as global variable
pygame.init()
screen_size = 400
global window
window = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_size,screen_size))
pygame.display.set_caption("evolution simulator")
window.fill((255,255,255))
pygame.display.update()

def draw_Window():
    global grid
    blockSize = 20
    # grid = []
    for row in range(20):#NO IT ISNT
        for column in range(20):
            grid = numpy.zeros((20,20))
```

Using a matrix to make it easier to call points within the grid and aswell as troubleshooting.

```
rect = pygame.Rect(row*blockSize, column*blockSize,blockSize, blockSize)
            pygame.draw.rect(window,(0,0,0), rect, 1)

class spurgs:
    def __init__(self,age,hunger,speed,gender,x,y,race):
        # 1 for male, 2 for female
        self.hunger = hunger
        self.speed = speed
        self.gender = gender
        self.age = age
        self.race = race
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.size = 8
        self.death = False


    def update(self):
        if self.death == False:
            self.age = self.age + 1
            self.draw()
        if self.age <= 100:
            coin_flip = random.randint(1,2)
            if coin_flip == 1:
                self.death == True
        for row in range(20):
            for column in range(20):
                # print(self.x,self.y)
                # print(len(grid))
                if self.x > 20:
                    print("Hello")

                elif self.x > 20:
                    print("goodbye")
                if grid[self.x,self.y] == 0:
                    grid[self.x,self.y] = 1

#MATRIX

#SURVIVAL ELEMENTS
    def eat(self):
        self.hunger +=1
        #remove some food  to affect global food resource
    def breed(self,mate):
        # In the generation class, make a list for the next generation and append baby to the list
        pass
# MOVEMENT
    def move(self,dir):
        if self.death == False:
            if dir == 1:
                self.x += 1
                self.update()

#DRAWING
    def draw(self):
        # x =1 , y =4
        #for grid system
        if self.death ==False:
            #{Pixel Converter}
            x = self.x * 20 - 10
            y = self.y * 20 - 10
            pygame.draw.circle(window,self.race,(x,y),self.size)
# GENERATION class
class generation:
    def __init__(self,size):
        self.size = size + 1
        self.currentGen = []
    def makeGeneration(self):
        for i in range(self.size):

            self.seed_mutations = random.randint(0,20)
```

On each iteration up "size" the x and y is randomized from 0,20 but it isn't working as should be:

```
self.x = random.randint(0,20)
            self.y = random.randint(0,20)
            self.gender = random.randint(1,2)
#Race chooser

            race = random.randint (1,4)
            if race == 1:
                self.color_race = (0, 110, 255)
            elif race == 2:
                self.color_race = (255, 234, 0)
            if race == 3:
                self.color_race = (132, 0, 255)
            if race == 4:
                self.color_race = (242, 53, 53)
            print(self.x,self.y)
            self.currentGen.append(spurgs(1,self.seed_mutations,self.seed_mutations,self.gender,self.x,self.y,self.color_race))
    def update(self):
        for m in self.currentGen:
            m.update()
```

Ignore this class still being developed a few easily fixed bugs.

```
class food:
    def __init__(self,type):
        self.type = type
        if self.type == "m":
            self.hunger_val = 5
        elif self.type == "a":
            self.hunger_val = 1
        self.eaten = False
    def random_x_y(self):
        self.x = random.randint(0,20)
        self.y = random.randint(0,20)


    def draw(self):
        self.random_x_y()
        if self.eaten == False:
            if self.type =="m":
                pygame.draw.circle(window,(10,255,50),(self.x,self.y),self.hunger_val)
            elif self.type == "a":
                pygame.draw.circle(window,(0,0,0),(self.x,self.y),self.hunger_val)

    def update(self):
        if self.eaten == False:
            self.draw()
            for row in range(20):
                for column in range(20):
                    # print(self.x,self.y)
                    if grid[self.x,self.y] == 0:
                        grid[self.x,self.y] = 2
                    if grid[self.x,self.y] == 1:
                        self.eaten = True

a = food("m")
a.draw()

gen_1 = generation(8)
gen_1.makeGeneration()

run = True

while run:
    #WINDOW
    print
    window.fill((255,255,255))
    draw_Window()
    #QUIT CONDITION
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            print("closing the loop")
            run = False

    #TESTING
    gen_1.update()
    a.update()

    #FINAL LOOP
    pygame.display.update()
    pygame.time.delay(1000)

pygame.quit()
```

If there are any coding practices I am not following please feel free to show me them, Also some of the indention levels are a bit messed up.

Comment: I can't see any sense in the nested loops in the `update` method. Do you mean `grid[row,column]` rather than `grid[self.x,self.y]`?

Comment: `self.x` is incremented even if `self.x` is 19 in the `move` method.